# Preprocess image: how to get parent entity?

Tags: 8, entities, media, theming

I'm using responsive images (single `img` tag with `srcset` and `sizes` attributes). My content editors can manipulate the displayed size of the image with a custom field on a shared parent entity. Therefore I can't meaningfully use the sizes field from the responsive image module, because my editors can set the image size from 10% of a fixed container up to 100vw on per paragraph level.

I know how to preprocess the sizes attributes, but I don't know how to get to my shared parent entity, which holds the field determining the size of the image's parent container:

```
function template_preprocess_responsive_image(&$variables) {
  // pseudocode: don't know how to this
  $imageField = $variables['whatever'];
  $parentParagraph = $imageField->getParentMediaEntity()->getParentParagraphEntity();
}
```

My question is how do I get the parent paragraph entity as written above in pseudocode?

Comment: Could you check the value of `$variables['#item']`? It seems that the [viewElements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!responsive_image!src!Plugin!Field!FieldFormatter!ResponsiveImageFormatter.php/function/ResponsiveImageFormatter%3A%3AviewElements/8.2.x) function of the field formatter adds `$file->_referringItem` to the render array, which I'd expect to be the parent entity.

Comment: Yes, but this is another hook, `template_preprocess_responsive_image_formatter() ` and you get the field item, which parent is the field and the grandparent is the paragraph.

Comment: ... which you can get with this shortcut [FieldItemBase::getEntity](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21FieldItemBase.php/function/FieldItemBase%3A%3AgetEntity/8.4.x): $parentEntity = $imageField->getEntity();

Comment: OK, seems I've had the wrong starting point with `hook_preprocess_responsive_image()`. Using `hook_preprocess_responsive_image_formatter()` and `$entity = $variables['item']->getEntity();` I'm getting my media entity. Thanks for your help, I'll post an answer as soon as I have a working code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the the "real" code counterpart to the pseudecode from the question:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_responsive_image_formatter(array &$variables) {
  // get the imagefield's parent entity
  $fieldParent = $variables['item']->getEntity();

  // this line is only needed if using media entities (= entity references)
  // must disable entity view caching to work correctly
  $fieldParent = $fieldParent->_referringItem->getEntity();

  // get the image width from the custom field
  $myImgSizes = $fieldParent->get('field_image_size')->getString();
  // can't change attribute here => store it temporarily
  $variables['responsive_image']['#attributes']['data-overridesizes'] = $myImgSizes;
}

function THEMENAME_preprocess_responsive_image(array &$variables) {
  //override sizes attribute with my calculated value
  if (key_exists('data-overridesizes', $variables['img_element']['#attributes'])) {
    $variables['img_element']['#attributes']['sizes'] = $variables['img_element']['#attributes']['data-overridesizes'];
    unset($variables['img_element']['#attributes']['data-overridesizes']);
  }
}
```

If using media (=entity references) you also have to disable view cache for entites ([see this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/210825/how-can-i-ensure-a-referenced-entity-is-cached-separately-per-paragraph))

```
function MODULENAME_entity_view(&$build, $entity, $display, $view_mode) {
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'media' && $entity->bundle() == 'image' && $view_mode == 'my_uncached_viewmode'){
    unset($build['#cache']['keys']);
  }
}
```

Comment: Answer is not yet fully correct, when using the same media on different paragraphs, I always get the first paragraph referencing the media, instead of the real parent.

Comment: Then you have to disable caching. You can do this for all media entities in the entity type definition by adding `render_cache = FALSE` or create a view mode and add to the config yaml file `cache: false`.

Comment: Thanks, already found another question dealing with the cache issue, posted my final, working code

Comment: Thank you so much for this information! I didn't realize that `_referringItem` is unreliable due to caching. Turns out it was the source of my bug and setting `cache: false` within the config yaml file for my view mode fixed it.

It appears there is an open issue for this on Drupal.org: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2908449

I agree with the issue creator that accessing parent entities is really important so I hope somebody works on it. It's way out of my league.